How can I convert f-strings to .format()?
I have this function, which uses f-strings to print a number of variables:
def myfunc(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'fruit' and 'juice' in kwargs:
        print(f"I like {' and '.join(args)} and my favorite fruit is {kwargs['fruit']}")
        print(f"May I have some {kwargs['juice']} juice?")
    else:
        pass
        
myfunc('eggs','spam',fruit='cherries',juice='orange')

I want to change from f-strings to format(). How can i do that?

This question is similar to: String formatting: % vs. .format vs. f-string literal. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use {} as a placeholder for your values, then pass the required kwargs and args vars as arguments to format():
def myfunc(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'fruit' and 'juice' in kwargs:
        print("I like {} and my favorite fruit is {}".format(' and '.join(args), kwargs['fruit']))
        print("May I have some {} juice?".format(kwargs['juice']))
    else:
        pass

myfunc('eggs', 'spam', fruit='cherries', juice='orange')

Output:
I like eggs and spam and my favorite fruit is cherries
May I have some orange juice?

